# Disable IIS client certificate trust check and validation

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

We have some custom client certificate validation in our ASP.NET Core application. It works perfectly fine when running standalone (i.e., using only the Kestrel server). However, in production we want to have an IIS in front of our Kestrel. IIS unfortunately performs its own validation / trust checks and deems the client certificate invalid (returning 403.16).

How to overcome this? How to disable client cert validation + trust check in IIS? IIS should simply forward us the client certificate and do nothing else with it. We explicitly do not want to import the client certificate into the trusted root store (or in any certificate store on the machine).

Comment: Have you enabled the client certificate authentication or other authentication mode in the IIS?  You could see it by using IIS management console's authentication icon.

Comment: No, we have not.

Comment: @D.R. Have you found any solution for this? We are facing same issue.

Comment: We've gone a different way, however, a colleague of mine pointed out that writing our own IIS Module or IIS Handler could do the trick. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I guess the root certificate of the certification authority is not in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities certificate store on the IIS Web server. So you face this issue.

I suggest you could follow below steps to import it.

1.On the IIS Web server, click Start, type mmc.exe in the Start Search box, right-click mmc.exe, and then click Run as administrator.

2.On the File menu, click Add/Remove Snap-in.

3.Under Available snap-ins, click Certificates, and then click Add.

4.Click Computer account, and then click Next.

5.Click Local computer, click Finish, and then click Close.

6.To exit the wizard, click OK.

7.Expand Certificates, expand Trusted Root Certification Authorities, right-click Certificates, point to All Tasks, and then click Import.

8.In the Certificate Import Wizard, click Next.

9.In the File name box, type the location of the root certificate of the certification authority, and then click Next.

10.Click Next, and then click Finish.

More details, you could refer to this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/942061/error-message-when-you-visit-a-web-site-that-is-hosted-on-iis-7-0-http).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out how to import certificates into the trusted root store, however, we explicitly want to allow client certificates which are NOT known in this store beforehand. Sorry, if this wasn't clear in the question, I'll try to improve the question.

Comment: In my opinion, you could use a CA to sign all the certificate, your server just need to trust this CA, all the client certificate will be trusted.

Comment: Does this work for non Windows environments too. And how do I exclude all but one trusted root certificate for apps with high security requirements?